# Insufficient Privileges : <apex:detail account

Tags: visualforce, account, insufficient-privileges

I'm using standard object (Account) and if I add the `<apex:detail` as shown below then I'm getting `Insufficient Privileges` what do I need to do?

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="acts">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Passing of Parameters">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acts}" var="a">
                <!--apex:column value="{!a.Name}" /-->
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="{!a.Name}" reRender="detail">
                        <apex:param name="passingId" value="{!a.Id}" />
                        <apex:param name="pasingName" value="{!a.Name}" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Type}" />
                <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}" />
                <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageBlock title="Account Detail" id="detail"   >  
                 <apex:detail subject=" {!$CurrentPage.parameters.pasingName}" relatedList="false" />              
            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have object-level and FLS permissions to the Account object and all the fields you're accessing? When do you see the error? When you load the page or when you click on an action?

Comment: When click to display the detail of the account's record

Comment: To be more specific, when you click on the commandLink button?

Comment: Yes when click on command link button

Comment: This is the line that's erroring: `<apex:detail subject=" {!$CurrentPage.parameters.pasingName}" relatedList="false" />` . I would guess that the reason is that pasingName is not in the page params. I'm not sure that what you want to do can be done with just a standard controller. Perhaps you could try an extension controller to store the ID of the account you want to see the detail of?

Comment: Based on the way you've written the VF page, parameter pasingName looks like the account name, not the accountId.  You seem to have another parameter called passingId that looks more relevant